# Suppose $D$ is a 0-1 random variable, does $E(X|Y,D)=0$ imply that $E(X|Y)=0$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $X,Y,D$ are random variables, and $D$ only takes two values 0 and 1. If $E(X|Y,D)=0$, can we conclude that $E(X|Y)=0$?

Comment: This follows from the [*towering property* for conditional expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation#Proof_in_the_general_case): if $\mathcal{G}_{\text{small}} \subseteq \mathcal{G}_{\text{big}}$ are $\sigma$-algebras, then $$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid \mathcal{G}_{\text{big}}] \mid \mathcal{G}_{\text{small}}] = \mathbb{E}[X \mid \mathcal{G}_{\text{small}}]. $$ In your case, you can take $\mathcal{G}_{\text{big}} = \sigma(Y, D)$ and $\mathcal{G}_{\text{small}} = \sigma(Y)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$E(X|Y) = E(E(X|Y,D)|Y) = E(0|Y) = 0$$

The first equality can be derived as,

$RHS = E(E(X|Y,D)|Y) \\ = \int_{d}\int_{x} xf(x|y,d)f(d|y)\partial x\partial d \\= \int_{d}\int_{x} x\frac{f(x,y,d)}{f(d|y)f(y)}f(d|y)\partial x\partial d \\ = \int_{d}\int_{x} x\frac{f(x,y,d)}{f(y)}\partial x\partial d \\ = \int x\frac{f(x,y)}{f(y)}\partial x \\ = \int x f(x|y)\partial x \\ = E(X|Y)$

Replace $\int$ with $\sum$ for  discrete random variable.